# Noticed a weird behaviour of JS object, can anyone help me out?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, web, vuejs3

I'm working on a VueJS project and I had some code which was preparing a payload object and passing it to backend. The value in the payload was coming from accessing a ref() variable.

Here's an example:

```
let payload = {
  accNo: acc.value //acc is a ref("Some Value")
};

console.log(payload)

postCallToBe(payload);
```

The backend didn't get appropriate payload, it was getting accNo: true whereas it should've been accNo: "Some Value". I checked it in the console and it printed:

{ accNo: 'Some Value' }

But here comes the fun part, upon clicking the arrow next to the object and expanding it I saw

{
accNo: true
}

I couldn't wrap my head around what's causing the value to mutate from a string to boolean when clearly I'm not doing anything else than what I've mentioned above.

I tweaked my code a bit like below

```
postCallToBe({accNo:acc.value});
```

and now surprisingly correct value was being passed to the backend.

I'd really appreciate if someone can explain this whole phenomenon to me.

Thanks.

Comment: This suggests that you have code that mutates `payload`  *after* you have made the call to `console.log`.

Comment: The phenomenon could be due to object logging being [lazily evaluated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log_static#logging_objects), i.e. your browser will only evaluate the object's inner properties once you interact with it (click the arrow).  This can lead to discrepancies between what you see and what you expect at the exact time you console.log.  One way to mitigate this is logging your object wrapped in `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))` which will always log the object as it was at the actual time of logging.

Comment: For understanding why this happens, see the linked questions. If you need further help resolving the issue, please post all the code that works with the `payload` object so that we can reproduce the issue.